# button that takes pictures within expanding uitableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

Okay i have a `UITableView` with custom expanding cells. there is a .xib .m and .h for the cells. i am trying to have a button that opens the camera to take a picture and save it within the cell the button was pressed. but it is not working. i have researched for the past few days and cannot find any solution. this is my code in .m file for the expanding cell:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

[scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button sizeToFit];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

button.center = CGPointMake( 25, 50);

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self addSubview:button];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[picker setDelegate:self];
picker.allowsImageEditing = NO;
//[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
//[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
}
```

i keep getting the error in the lines that are commented out of the buttonPressed method it says `"no visible @interface for 'ExpandingCell' declares the selector 'presentModalExpandingCell:animated:'"` I've tried them both (not at the same time) and got the same error. i am new at iOS programming and not sure what this means so i have no idea where to start to fix it.

should i be trying this in the ViewController the tableview is in instead of in the expanding cell? 
any help or guidance is appreciated. thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the view controller into the cell, just assign it, then in the button press action calls presentModalExpandingCell:animated with this view controller.

Comment: im not sure what you mean by that. could you please go into more detail?

Comment: in you cell class , you add a property assign the view controller(that contains your table view). Then in your present method ,you can use this view controller. It is import that you can retain the view controller ,or it will cause the retain cycle.

Comment: so in the cell .h file put "@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *ViewController4;"? i tried putting the viewcontrollers name instead of "UIViewController" and got another error.